# FileNotFoundException ResourceManage::GetString C++/CLI

Tags: .net-4.0, mfc, resources, c++-cli, managed

I have a MFC DLL with CLR enabled and using .Net v4.0 in VS2010 SP1. I have added a new managed resource file called ReportStrings.resx to the root of the project.  I am using the code below to access the resources.  No matter what I put in the ResourceManger constructor.  I am getting a FileNotFoundException when rmResources->GetString(sKey) is called.  The exception says "Could not find file 'Report.resources'."  I searched my application for any references to Report.resources and did not find any.  Any help would be gretaly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

```cpp
public ref class ResourceGetter
{
  static ResourceManager^ rmResources = gcnew ResourceManager("Report.ReportStrings", Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly());

  public:
    static String^ GetResource(String^ sKey)
    {
      String^ sReturn = nullptr;
      String^ sTheme = String::Empty;

      try
      {
        sReturn = rmResources->GetString(sKey);
      }
      catch (Exception^ ex)
      {
        ex;
      }

      return (sReturn == nullptr) ? "[" + sKey + " not found]" : sReturn;
    }
};
```

Comment: Run ildasm.exe on your executable, double-click the manifest and look for the .mresource.  It should be something like mumble.ReportStrings.resources with the *mumble* part unguessable from your question.

Comment: @Hans Passant - This is what I found in the manifest: ".mresource public Report.ReportStrings.resources".  This is also the name of the compiled resource in the Debug directory.

Comment: `Could not find file 'Report.resources'` was that a typo or does the exception actually say 'Report.ReportStrings.resource'?  I would also avoid initializing rmResources like that.  Best to do so in the constructor of some class so you can be sure that the assembly is correct.

Comment: @Hans Passant - The error does say 'Report.resources'.  I have tried changing the base name in the ReportManager constructor and it always returns the same error with 'Report.resources'.  I have moved ReportManager constructor to an initialize function and I have verified that the correct assembly is being returned.  I have also verified that the assembly contains 'Report.ReportStrings.resources' and does not contain 'Report.resources'.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after creating several test projects and recreating my application project from scratch I seem to have found the issue.  If I initialize the resources in the app constructor of my main file everything works correctly.  So for example, my project is named Report, so I add the initailization code to the CReportApp constructor in the Report.cpp file and all is well.  Thanks for your help Hans Passant.  My code is below:

ResourceGetter.h

```cpp
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Resources;

public ref class ResourceGetter
{
  static ResourceManager^ rmResources = nullptr;

  public:
    static ResourceGetter()
    {
    }

    static void Initialize()
    {
      if ( rmResources == nullptr )
      {
        rmResources = gcnew ResourceManager("Report.ReportStrings", Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly());
        ResourceProxy::Initialize(gcnew Mnc::Utilities::GetResourceDelegate(&ResourceGetter::GetResource));
      }
    }

    static String^ GetResource(String^ sKey)
    {
      String^ sReturn = nullptr;

      try
      {
        if ( rmResources != nullptr )
          sReturn = rmResources->GetString(sKey);
        else
          System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Failed to retrieve resource (" + sKey + "): Returned null.");
      }
      catch (Exception^ ex)
      {
        ex;
      }

      return (sReturn == nullptr) ? "[" + sKey + " not found]" : sReturn;
    }
};
```

Report.cpp

```cpp
CReportApp::CReportApp()
{
  ResourceGetter::Initialize();
}
```